# create dynamic depended attributes on create page form with Nuxeo Studio

Tags: nuxeo

I need to create a dynamic form based on the user input data, for ex if I check e  checkbox  on create page automatically page should displayed same other fields.

Have any body any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at nuxeo documentation :  https://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC/How+to+Impact+Another+JSF+Component+from+a+Command+or+Select